# Relations system between two objects of a Person class

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say I have an `ObservableCollection<Person>`.

Now, every student can have some sort of opinion on every other person. What would be the best way to code something like this, so that it's accessible from both objects?

I thought about something like this for a relations:

```
enum RelationPoint { Neutral, Like, Dislike, Love, Hate }
List<RelationPoint> relation;
```

How can I define something like this for every person?

Comment: you could have each person object store a collection of Relationship objects that have a Relation point and a person object that is a reference to the person the opinion is of.

Comment: Have you considered giving each person object a dictionary property of type `<int, RelationPoint>`? Assuming each person object has a unique Id of some sort, you could just use the dictionary to insert an entry with another person's id as the key and the `RelationPoint` as the value.

Comment: That's exactly what I've decided to do. Thanks

Comment: You have to mind, that your relation has a direction. So, if you store all relations in only one list, then you have to filter for from/to. Or instead you can use two list on each person.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to make an object called "Relation" which contains 2 persons.

So you would have following classes:

```
public class Person
{
   public String Name;
   ....
}
```

and a class "Relation:

```
public class Relation
{
   private Person p1;
   private Person p2;
   private String opinion;
}
```

Now you could make sth. like this:

```
Person p = new Person ("John");
Person p2 = new Person ("David");
Relation r1 = new Relation(p, p2, "Neutral");
```

Just one of many solutions.

Comment: Thanks I've decided to use a Dictionary for this. I somehow forgot something like this existed xD

Comment: Don't forget opinions are bi-directional, e.g. p2 might have different feelings for p1 than vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object, which stores the opinion in an object, like this:

```
public class Opinion
{
    public Person Destination
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Person Target
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public RelationPoint RelationType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

If you store them like this in a list, every person can have an opinion abount another pserson.

To figure out, which person has which optinion, you can simply find this out using linq:

```
var goodRelation = listOfOption.Where(item => item.RelationType == RelationPoint.Like && item.Destination = <<Some Person>>);
```

Now you know, which person the `Destination` likes.